# Android webview is not displaying image

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I was just learning how to display a html file using webview Android.

But the image containing on html file are not displaying on the Android version greater than kitkat.

My code is:

```
MainActivity.java inside oncreate

WebView web = (WebView)finditembyid(R.id.webview1);

Web.loadurl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

**My html file contains:**

```
  <img src="image.png">
```

**Inside my assets folder:**

```
Index.html
Image.png
```

I tried changing the src on image tag by:

```
Src="file:////android_asset/image.png
Src="/android/image.png"
```

But these are not working.
What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code out,its a sample code in which i have opened content in webview thats contains a hyperlink and image as well.
It works for me if there is a link it will create it automatically and if there in image tag then it will display image in webview.

```
String about_us_description_new = "<html><body style=color:black;>" + "<p align=\"justify\">" + about_us_description + "</p>" + "</body></html>";
                webView2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView2.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, about_us_description_new.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

replace your content with "about_us_description", i have stored content in a string variable as about_us_description and then did my work .

Hope this helps you out

Comment: HI Apoorv Mehrotra, he has already have html file in asset folder, then why you are creating about_us_description_new  again

Comment: Exactly i have my file as html but i can use inputstream